# I'm switching mobile phone service and I want to port over my contacts

Tags: contacts, internal-storage

So I have a Droid Razr and I backed up my entire phone to a 7zip file. All I want to get is my contacts and a specific picture and ringtone. I got the picture and the ringtone but I don't know where to find my contacts. I have a lot of them so I don't want to lose them. It would be much easier if I weren't switching phone services because the sim card is Verizon and I could just switch the simcard in and let the contacts transfer like that. But I'm switching to Metro so the sim card won't do anything. At least I don't think it will.

Comment: Are you changing phone too, or just the SIM card?

Answer (score 0):

If you're just after the contacts, that should be easy as 1-2-3:

1. open the *contacts* app, tap the menu, chose "Export to SDCard"
2. copy the resulting file (in most cases named something like `0001.vcf` over to the new phone
3. on the new phone, same as in 1. – just chose to "Import from SDCard"

Of course, there are several more alternatives – depending on your preferences:

- if you've synchronized your contacts with Google (or some other cloud service), they should automatically be synced to your new device as soon as you connect it with your account
- plenty of [backup/restore apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=32) are available to assist you, some even specific to contacts
- more information might be found in our [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info)